# Write CSV file with rearranged columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am new to Python development and trying to write to csv file. I have an *in.csv* file and I need some of its columns written to *out.csv*. Input csv has columns "a,b,c,d,e" and I need only columns "a,d,b" rearranged. When I try to achieve this it throws an error as given below.

Below is my code:

```
import csv

fileName = r"D:\in.csv"
out_list = ['a','d','b']
with open(fileName, 'r') as infile, open(r"D:\out.csv",'w+',newline='') as 
outfile:
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=out_list)
writer.writeheader()
for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
    # writes the reordered rows to the new file
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Below is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/test.py", line 11, in <module>
writer.writerow(row)
File 
"C:\Users\Laxmikant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\csv.py", 
line 153, in writerow
return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
File 
"C:\Users\Laxmikant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\csv.py", 
line 149, in _dict_to_list
+ ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'e', 'c'
```

Contents of *in.csv*:

```
a,b,c,d,e  
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1  
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2  
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3  
a4,b4,c4,d4,e4
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: In Pycharm it gives error as "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)"

Comment: @LaxmikantRaikar the IDEs like pycharm are bad to give information about this type of errors, the best thing is that you execute it in the CMD or terminal and you will get the complete error message, on the other hand if you want help you must provide a [mcve], not a piece of code that you need to define several things.

Comment: @ Thanks for your response ,sorry that I did not provided full code.error msg from cmd "Trace back (most recent call last):
  File "CSV_Ninja.py", line 1215, in arrange_accept
    writer.writerow(row)
  File "C:\Users\Laxmikant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\Laxmikant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\csv.py", line 149, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Variable_category'"

Comment: @LaxmikantRaikar execute `print(out_list)` before `with open(fileName, 'r') ...` and show the content of outfile, please provide a [mcve] and use `@eyllanesc`

Comment: @eyllanesc here is what I get after adding print(out_list)   "['Year', 'Level', 'Industry_code_NZSIOC', 'Industry_name_NZSIOC', 'Units']  after that the same error appears

Comment: @LaxmikantRaikar Well, as I have told you several times, if you want help you must provide a [mcve], but unfortunately no one will help you.

Comment: thanks for all your suggestions,thank you @eyllanesc you suggested several times to provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.As I new to stackoverflow now I get your point and changed code accordingly.Hope this is what you suggested and if you need any further info please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your support,  I solved this by changing

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=out_list)
```

to

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=out_list, extrasaction ='ignore')
```

adding

```
extrasaction ='ignore'
```

solved issue.